# How to dynamically allocate array of structs inside a function in C

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I am trying to dynamically size an array of struts inside a function which is reading data in from a file, so I do not know size at compile time.

I am getting an error when populating the dynamically allocated arrays "Exception thrown: write access violation) in the main on one of the lines assigning values to this array on a (seemingly)random index, like `i=170` in `(mystruct_array)[i].b = i` in main, suggesting that I am not correctly allocating the memory in the function.  I have searched here but can't find what I am doing wrong - I appreciate it is probably something trivial I am missing.  So, please, what am I doing wrong here?

```
#define ELEMENT_COUNT   10000

typedef struct mystruct
{
    uint64_t a;
    uint64_t b;
    uint64_t c;
} mystruct_t;

void test(mystruct_t ** p_struct_array, uint32_t * p_count)
{
    *p_count = ELEMENT_COUNT;
    *p_struct_array = malloc(ELEMENT_COUNT * sizeof(mystruct_t *));
}

void main()
{
    mystruct_t * mystruct_array = NULL;
    uint32_t count;
    test(&mystruct_array, &count);
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < ELEMENT_COUNT; i++)
    {
        (mystruct_array)[i].a = i;
        (mystruct_array)[i].b = i;
        (mystruct_array)[i].c = i;
    }
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*p_struct_array = malloc(ELEMENT_COUNT * sizeof(mystruct_t *));
```

should be

```
*p_struct_array = malloc(ELEMENT_COUNT * sizeof(mystruct_t));
```

You want to allocate an array of 10000 `mystruct_t`s, not 10000 pointers.

---

Many people suggest avoiding bugs like this by always following a pattern like

```
ptr = malloc(count * sizeof(*ptr));
```

which in your case would read

```
*p_struct_array = malloc(ELEMENT_COUNT * sizeof(**p_struct_array));
```

and indeed the type of `**p_struct_array` is `mystruct_t`, not `mystruct_t *`.